# Constructing a type check parser with parser combinators

Tags: scala, generics, casting, parser-combinators

Currently, I'm trying to parse a `Reader[Token]` in Scala. Therefore, I'd like to check during the parsing steps if a `Token` is element of a specific class (e.g. `AToken`).
I can do that easily with the following code:

```
def aToken = acceptIf(_.isInstanceOf[AToken])("Token " + _ + " is not of type AToken")
  ^^ { _.asInstanceOf[AToken] }
```

This works perfectly fine. But I have several types to check. So for every type, I need to write that whole thing above again.
So I'd like some abstract `acceptIfInstanceOf[T]` method that automatically (magically?) creates one for type `T`.

My current solution is still a two-step thing:

```
def acceptIfInstanceOf[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]) : Parser[Elem] =
  acceptIf(_.getClass == m.runtimeClass)("" + _ + " is not of type " + m)
def aToken = acceptIfInstanceOf[AToken] ^^ { _.asInstanceOf[AToken] }
```

This works too, but I'd like to get rid of the function application in `aToken` and include it directly in `acceptIfInstanceOf`.
Sadly, this doesn't work:

```
def acceptIfInstanceOf[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]) : Parser[T] =
  acceptIf(_.getClass == m.runtimeClass)("" + _ + " is not of type " + m)
  ^^ { m.runtimeClass.cast(_) }
```

I get the following error message from the Scala compiler:

```
scala: type mismatch;
found   : _$1 where type _$1
required: T
def acceptIfInstanceOf[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]): Parser[T] =
  acceptIf(_.getClass == m.runtimeClass)("" + _ + " is not of type " + m)
  ^^ { m.runtimeClass.cast(_) }
                          ^
```

Does someone know if and how it is possible to construct such a thing?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to compose the working `acceptIfInstanceOf` with `_.asInstanceOf[T]`? Like that `acceptIf(_.getClass == m.runtimeClass)("" + _ + " is not of type " + m) ^^ {_.asInstanceOf[T] }`

Comment: I completely oversaw this. Yes, `_.asInstanceOf[T]` works. Thanks! However, I have to tweak my code, because it does not consider Subtypes. E.g. with `class BToken extends AToken`, then `acceptIfInstanceOf[AToken]` does not accept any `BToken`s - which it should ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `_.asInstaceOf[T]` instead `m.runtimeClass.cast(_)` as stated by [huynhjl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257449/huynhjl%20huynhjl) solves the initial problem:

```
def acceptIfInstanceOf[T](implicit m: Manifest[T]) : Parser[T] =
  acceptIf(_.getClass == m.runtimeClass)("" + _ + " is not of type " + m)
  ^^ { _.asInstanceOf[T] }
```

However, the check `_.getClass == m.runtimeClass` obviously ignores all subtype semantics that `_.isInstanceOf` contains - simply because we check equality of two `Class` objects.

If I want to maintain the semantics of `isInstanceOf`, I have to use the following test:

```
reflect.ClassManifest.singleType(_) <:< m
```

But as this is deprecated in 2.10, I replaced `Manifest` by `TypeTag` and use now the following:

```
def acceptIfInstanceOf[T](implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Parser[T] =
  acceptIf(currentMirror.reflect(_).symbol.toType <:< typeOf[T])
  ("" + _ + " is not of type " + tag.tpe)
  ^^ { _.asInstanceOf[T] }
```

I got the above solution from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827365/replacing-deprecated-manifest-type-witness-in-scala-2-10) on Stack Overflow.